# Segue From Custom UIView which is alertview to UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview, segue

I have a button on UIViewController on click of that button an UIview gets poped up like alertview which has tableview in it.Now on selection of table cell i would like to segue to the detail viewcontroller

Here's [the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17103400/is-it-possible-to-segue-from-a-uitableviewcell-on-a-uiview-to-another-view) to which i refered but none of them worked for me

For alertview i have used (https://github.com/kwent/ios-custom-alertview)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

@yar1vn's answer is right, however, I'll describe more precisely what you need to do.

Custom alert view from your link has a `delegate` property, which should conform to protocol

```
@protocol CustomIOS7AlertViewDelegate

- (void)customIOS7dialogButtonTouchUpInside:(id)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex;

@end
```

that means you should implement this method in your UIViewController.

in .h file:

```
@interface YourViewController : UIViewController <YourViewController>

...

@end
```

in .m file:

```
@implementation YourViewController

...

- (void)customIOS7dialogButtonTouchUpInside:(id)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"YourSegue" sender:nil];
}
```

and set the delegate when creating alertView:

```
[alertView setDelegate:self];
```

`@"YourSegue"` is the segue from the controller which shows alertView to the detail view controller.

I disagree that you should use UIAlertController, since if your deployment target is iOS 7 (which is reasonable) you should not use new features of iOS 8

**EDIT:**

if you want to launch segue from tap on table view cell, you should call `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"YourSegue" sender:nil]` from tableView's delegate method `-tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`

I assume you have set current view controller as tableView's dataSource and delegate, so add to your view controller

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"YourSegue" sender:nil];
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

though setting the UIView as delegate is not the best approach, we can handle it :)

I see two solutions:

the first is to add the controller as the property to your view like this:

```
@interface YourView : UIView <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

@property (nonatomic, weak) YourViewController *parentController;

...
```

somewhere (probably, in `-viewDidLoad`) you set this property as

```
youViewInstance.parentController = self;
```

and the in view's delegate method call

```
[self.parentController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"YouSegue" sender:nil]
```

the second one is to simply set the controller as tableView's delegate and call `performSegue:` from its method. And you should describe all details more completely :)

Comment: but this will work for button click...can u plz tell me how to do with tableview cell selection...??

Comment: i tried this.but it say performsequewithidentifier is not possible in uiview

Comment: bro there is no viewdidload in uiviewalert... and i m not able to perform the 2nd step in edit no 2... plz help

Comment: also plz check what will be the view instance in [link](https://github.com/kwent/ios-custom-alertview/tree/master/CustomIOS7AlertView/CustomIOS7AlertView/View)... i m not getting it :(

Comment: Bro did u get the solution for this??

Comment: @HardikAmal you add this property to the AlertView class and then in view controller's `viewDidLoad`, that is presenting this alert view, set the pointer from view to controller. This means manual changing the code from the link, yeah

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use 3rd party AlertViews anymore. You can use the AlertController provided with iOS 8 SDK.
I don't know how this AlertView works but the readme mentions a delegate. Did you try calling the segue from the delegate method?